# How to set the end date of a reminder?

Tags: google-assistant

How should I utter the comment so it can understand the end date?

The following does not work:

> OK Google, remind me to do this every day at 3 for 5 weeks.

Comment: Try this: Ok Google, remind me to do X daily at Y up-to Z. where, X=topic for reminder, Y=time of reminder and Z=period of reminder.

Comment: @parthu_panther does not work